# adding column to dataframe based on count from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have a dataframe `ranksdf` containing `player names`, `dates`, and their `ranking` per the date. The date column is a parsed `datetime` object (maybe relevant for date comparison later):

```
player      date        ranking
A           20120601    1
B           20120601    2
C           20120601    3
A           20130601    1
B           20130601    2
C           20130601    3
```

What I want to do is to add a new column which counts `tournament wins` of each player until that date. the information on tournament wins comes from another dataframe called `matchesdf`:

```
t_name  t_date      w_name      round
X       20120101    A           F   
X       20120101    A           SF          
Y       20120201    B           F
Y       20120201    B           SF
Z       20130101    A           F
```

- `t_name` = tournament name
- `t_date` = date of the tournament
- `w_name` = winner name
- `round` = the round in the tournament. `F` = Final, `SF` = Semifinal

From the second dataframe I know *when* a specific *player* won a tournament at a give time by counting the rows where round equals `F`.

So what I want to do is to add a new column to `ranksdf` counting the tournament wins but only until `ranksdf.date`.

In pseudocode something like this: `ranksdf['t_wins'] = ranksdf.apply(lambda x: matchesdf[(matchesdf['t_date'] < x['date']) & (matchesdf['w_name'] == x['player']) & (matchesdf['round'] == 'F')].count())`

So, the constraints on looking up the info in `matchesdf` are the *time* (because I want to know only the wins until the time of the ranking in `ranksdf`), the *player name* obviously, and the *round* (because tournament wins are defined by winning the Final).

The result should look like this:

```
player      date        ranking     t_wins
A           20120601    1           1
B           20120601    2           1
C           20120601    3           0
A           20130601    1           2
B           20130601    2           1
C           20130601    3           0
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Your psuedocode looks like it (or something close to it) would work, though there are more efficient methods to reduce the number of lookups you would need.  For example, if you did a groupby player and then applied a custom function, you would only have to get the player data from matchesdf once per player.

Comment: thx for the comment. i tried my pseudo-code already, but it raises a KeyError: `KeyError: ('date', u'occurred at index date')` .. not sure how to solve it. it is related to this part of the query: `(matchesdf['t_date'] < x['date'])`

Comment: Could you post an array form of the data so I can play with it a bit?  Also, consider creating a new function to use in the apply for now until you can work the problem out.

Comment: i'm afraid i cant. i simplified above examples and the original files are csvs. so reducing them to a minimal example requires some more effort and that's what I basically already did above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add axis = 1 to your apply function and it will work:

```
ranksdf["t_wins"]  = ranksdf.apply(lambda x: len(matchesdf[(matchesdf['t_date'] < x['date']) & (matchesdf['w_name'] == x['player']) & (matchesdf['round'] == 'F')]), axis =1)
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it raises: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 49, placement implies 1`. I have no idea why.

Comment: fwiw: the script raises this error after some time.. so it may occur later after already doing some work? and 49 is the number of columns in `matchesdf`.

Comment: I modified it using len() instead of count...try it now

Comment: okay wow nice. that works well! :) yes. please allow a final question: the [first commentator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769832/adding-column-to-dataframe-based-on-count-from-another-dataframe/31770266#comment51471048_31769832) suggested to improve the code by grouping first by the player and then applying a custom function. how would that look like?

Comment: I checked and at least on a small amount of data, it is a bit slower.  The code looks something like `def get_date_wins(in_group):`
`temp = matchesdf[(matchesdf['w_name'] == in_group.name) & (matchesdf['round'] == 'F')]`   
`in_group["t_wins"] = in_group.apply(lambda x: len(temp[temp['t_date'] < x['date']]), axis=1)`
`return in_group`

`ranksdf.groupby("player").apply(get_date_wins)`

Comment: hwo to store this in a new column? should i do: `ranksdf = ranksdf.groupby("player").apply(get_date_wins)` ?

Comment: You add the column to the subgroup inside the apply function, and then when you return that subgroup it replaces the existing subgroup.